# Mongo query for nulls on a non-nullable field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongo collection with a field called amount that is of the type

```
int:true,double:true
```

In the collection I have a record

```
{
    "_id": "5a818b8bf5665f418a9ee944",
    "amount": null
}
```

If I then run a query such as

```
{ "amount": {"$ne": null} }
```

That record above is included in the results even though it is null.

If I changed the type of the field to

```
int:true,double:true,null:true
```

The query works as expected, but changing in production is not possible. What are the options?

Comment: How have you defined the type for the field, is it using some package like mongoose?

Comment: It is using Monk. We have not defined any type.

Comment: As described, I'm leaning toward this not being a problem at the MongoDB layer but at some other one (perhaps Monk?). [This playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GQG8047FyDT) shows your query working as you expect it to, right?